# Get jsonArray in required format

Tags: json, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have below code. This code is converting list of objects containing list of objects into json format.

```
package com.fg.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Question question = new Question();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        question.setQuestionId("1");
        question.setQuestionText("hello");
        Options option1 = new Options();
        option1.setOption1("1");
        option1.setAnswer("0");
        Options option2 = new Options();
        option2.setOption1("2");
        option2.setAnswer("0");
        Options option3 = new Options();
        option3.setOption1("3");
        option3.setAnswer("0");
        Options option4 = new Options();
        option4.setOption1("4");
        option4.setAnswer("1");     
        List<Options> options = new ArrayList<Options>();
        options.add(option1);
        options.add(option2);
        options.add(option3);
        options.add(option4);
        question.setOptions(options);
        Question newQuestion = null;
        try {
             newQuestion =(Question) question.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        questions.add(question);
        questions.add(newQuestion);
        for(Question ques: questions){
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("question", ques.getQuestionText());
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            array.put(obj);
            for (Options op : ques.getOptions())
            {
                JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    obj1.put("option", op.getOption1());
                    //obj.put("answer", op.getAnswer());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                array.put(obj1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

I am getting output in below format..

```
[{"question":"Who invented java ?"},{"option":"Charles babbage"},{"option":"james gosling"},{"option":"gavin king"},{"option":"dennis richie"},{"question":"What is java ?"},{"option":"OOPs"},{"option":"koops"},{"option":"joops"},{"option":"gaps"}]
```

But, I need this json in below format..

```
[{"question":"Who invented java ?","option":"Charles babbage","option":"james gosling","option":"gavin king","option":"dennis richie"},{"question":"What is java ?","option":"OOPs","option":"koops","option":"joops","option":"gaps"}]
```

How can i achieve this ? any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something and i got above mentioned output with below code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Question question = new Question();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        question.setQuestionId("1");
        question.setQuestionText("hello");
        Options option1 = new Options();
        option1.setOption1("1");
        option1.setAnswer("0");
        Options option2 = new Options();
        option2.setOption1("2");
        option2.setAnswer("0");
        Options option3 = new Options();
        option3.setOption1("3");
        option3.setAnswer("0");
        Options option4 = new Options();
        option4.setOption1("4");
        option4.setAnswer("1");     
        List<Options> options = new ArrayList<Options>();
        options.add(option1);
        options.add(option2);
        options.add(option3);
        options.add(option4);
        question.setOptions(options);
        Question newQuestion = null;
        try {
             newQuestion =(Question) question.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        questions.add(question);
        questions.add(newQuestion);
        for(Question ques: questions){
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("question", ques.getQuestionText());
            } catch (JSONException e1) {                
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
            int i =0;
            for (Options op : ques.getOptions())
            {               
                String arr[] = new String[4];
                arr[0]="option1";arr[1]="option2";arr[2]="option3";arr[3]="option4";                
                try {
                    obj.put(arr[i], op.getOption1());
                    i++;                    
                } catch (JSONException e) {                 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               

            }
            array.put(obj);
        }
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```